# table view cell selected state changes when goes to another viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, selectedindex

i have a custom UITableView Cell, i have selected a particular cell and goes to another ViewController, when i came back to first view controller, selected state of the cell is not visible. how will i unchanged the selected state of a cell after navigating from another viewControllers?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [timeSet count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   timeSettingCell *newCell = nil;
   newCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
   if(newCell == nil)
   {
    NSLog(@"newCell ===================");
    NSArray *nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"timeSettingCell"   owner:self options:nil];
    newCell  = [ nibViews lastObject];
    }
    newCell.timeLabel.text=[timeSet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (newCell.selected==YES) {
      newCell.highlighted=YES;
      newCell.timeImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioSelected.png"];
    }
    else {
      newCell.highlighted=NO;
      newCell.timeImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioNotSelected.png"];
    }
return newCell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
value=[[time1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]integerValue];

SettingsViewController *settings=[[SettingsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil andCounterValue:value];
[[self presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
index=indexPath.row;
[settings release];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
}
```

thank you

Comment: If you need any quries, let me know....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should memorize your cell state (selected or not) using a NSArray created as a singleton, ivar or NSUserDefault and then read its state in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

EDIT: Sample code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Do what you want

// This save the index of your selected cell on disk
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:indexPath.row forKey:@"selectedCell"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Create your cell

// Here you check if the cell should be selected or not
if (indexPath.row == [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"selectedCell"]) {
    newCell.highlighted=YES;
    newCell.timeImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioSelected.png"];
} else {
    newCell.highlighted=NO;
    newCell.timeImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioNotSelected.png"];
}

return aCell;
}
```

`NSUserDefaults` is useful to save data on your device and retrieve them later. This mean you can check your cell status even after closing and reopening your app.

To use `NSUserDefaults` you need to add a Settings.bundle to you project. Take a look at [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: :( a little bit confusing, sorry i am a beginner in objective c, can you please explain with code?

Comment: yah . now it works fine , thank you for the useful information.  i got it  :)  :)

Answer (score 2):

put like this, it'll work fine...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Comment: but this code is for deselecting a row, what i need is the selected state should not change after navigating from other view controllers,. tanq

Comment: are you poping from other viewController to mainViewController which is having tableview?

Comment: actually i have a tableviewcontroller which is presented as a modalViewController from mainViewController to select some values. when the second time i want to select the value, i want to show early selected row..  problem is solved now, but if you have any other method please tell me.